# The Brief Puzzle Hunt

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story

Recently, I was invited to give a speech during the kickoff phase of a local puzzlehunt. I’ve almost finished writing my first draft, but I just can’t figure out the best way to end it off. Can you guys help me out?

Here’s the draft:

> Welcome to the Brief Puzzle Hunt! Before we officially kick off our main event, I want to say a few things about the puzzling event we all cherish and love:
>
> - Many kinds of puzzles have a high puzzlehunt value, scientifically speaking, so don’t panic if at first glance they seem too hard!
> - Puzzles can originate from anywhere. My personal favorites come from Pittsburgh puzzlehunts on campus.
> - Wondering if $ \sqrt{16} $ should be $ 4 $ or $ -4 $? Take the puzzlehunt and you’ll find the answer!
> - Puzzlehunt helps you learn how to stay fit and take care of yourself.
> - Puzzles are so important to our lives that even musicians need puzzlehunts to perform properly!
> - When forming a team, make sure to have a puzzlehunt, otherwise it’ll be like AD’s team without AD.
> - Feeling disgusted and want others to know? Simply shout “Puzzlehunt!” and everyone around you will start feeling the same thing.
> - Finally, puzzlehunts are great ways to help identify the nuts and bolts in everything, especially when it comes to specific items.
>
> And with that, the Brief Puzzle Hunt will now commence! Good luck to all the teams participating, may the best team win, and as always, ______!

Again, the question is: **what phrase should I include at the end of this speech, and why?**

---

**HINT 1**

> I wonder why they called it the *Brief* Puzzle Hunt. Perhaps I can make my points brief as well?

**HINT 2**

> I feel like I used a specific word a few too many times. In my next draft, I might need to replace it with words that make more sense in context.

**HINT 3**

> To clear some things up: Many puzzles are *basic,* AD is Anthony Davis (who plays...), and the nuts and bolts can be identified because of their labels.

Comment: It seems like the basic strategy might be rot13(ercynpvat chmmyruhag jvgu bgure 'CU' jbeqf naq nooerivngvat). For example, the first one 'have a high puzzlehunt value' becomes rot13('unir n uvtu cU inyhr' ersreevat gb gur npvq onfr fpnyr).  This can be more concisely stated as rot13(ner onfvp) which makes the first statement make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **HAVE FUN**

As stated in @BobbyTables answer:

> In each phrase, the word *puzzlehunt* can be replaced by a 2 letter (hence the claim “brief”) acronym starting with **P** (for puzzle!)

Many kinds of puzzles have a high puzzlehunt value, scientifically speaking, so don’t panic if at first glance they seem too hard!

> **pH** *Scientific* measure of acidity that can measure the *hardness* of water

Puzzles can originate from anywhere. My personal favorites come from Pittsburgh puzzlehunts on campus.

> **pA** the abbreviation for Pennsylvania, where Pittsburgh can be found

Wondering if $ \sqrt{16} $ should be $ 4 $ or $ -4 $? Take the puzzlehunt and you’ll find the answer!

> **pV** [principal value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value)

Puzzlehunt helps you learn how to stay fit and take care of yourself.

> **pE** physical education

Puzzles are so important to our lives that even musicians need puzzlehunts to perform properly!

> **p_** piano as in the quiet music indication or an actual piano, both helpful for musicians to perform

When forming a team, make sure to have a puzzlehunt, otherwise it’ll be like AD’s team without AD.

> **pF** power forward [@Bobby Tables](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83252/46082)

Feeling disgusted and want others to know? Simply shout “Puzzlehunt!” and everyone around you will start feeling the same thing.

> **pU** phrase meaning “gross!” [@Bobby Tables](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83252/46082)

Finally, puzzlehunts are great ways to help identify the nuts and bolts in everything, especially when it comes to specific items.

> **pN** part number

Comment: Yep, that’s the phrase I was missing, well done! Once I finish delivering the completed speech, I’ll award the green tick to you :)

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the preformatted text blocks and include the MathJax. If you prefer the blocks, then you can roll back the edit

Comment: Ah nice job! So relieving to see the final answer all figured out.

Answer (score 5):

Brief

> They're all two letter acronyms(that start with p)

Many kinds of puzzles have a high puzzlehunt value, scientifically speaking, so don’t panic if at first glance they seem too hard!

> P.H (high value corresponding to basic in chemistry)(thanks @hugh)

Puzzles can originate from anywhere. My personal favorites come from Pittsburgh puzzlehunts on campus.

> P.C?(Petersen Center is the only on campus building at Pittsburgh starting with p, though Pittsburgh might be the P in this answer)

Wondering if 16−−√ should be 4 or −4? Take the puzzlehunt and you’ll find the answer!

> P.F (prime factor)

Puzzlehunt helps you learn how to stay fit and take care of yourself.

> P.E (physical education)

Puzzles are so important to our lives that even musicians need puzzlehunts to perform properly!

> 

When forming a team, make sure to have a puzzlehunt, otherwise it’ll be like AD’s team without AD.

> P.F (power forward)

Feeling disgusted and want others to know? Simply shout “Puzzlehunt!” and everyone around you will start feeling the same thing.

> P.U

Finally, puzzlehunts are great ways to help identify the nuts and bolts in everything, especially when it comes to specific items.

> P.L (parts list?)

Final Answer

> The second letters seem to be spelling a word but without the blanks I can't get the final answer yet.

Comment: Gur svefg bar: uvtu cU inyhr? Qhaab, whfg jung V gubhtug jura V fnj gur jbeq "fpvragvsvpnyyl". V'z abg rira fher vs vg'f na npebalz. [rot13]

Comment: Gur guveq bar: zvtug or CE (cbfvgvir ebbg) — *jbaqrevat vs $\sqrt{16}$ fubhyq or $4$ be $-4$? Gnxr gur cbfvgvir ebbg naq lbh’yy svaq gur nafjre!* [rot13]

Comment: Prime factors are also always positive by definition but both could work!

Comment: I think you might be on to something! Perhaps if you keep going you’ll find the phrase I’m missing?

Comment: Keep in mind hint 2 while you’re going about doing the necessary edits

Answer (score 2):

Partial to get brains rolling:

> Replace puzzlehunt with a word (Acronym?) that belongs there

•Many kinds of puzzles have a high puzzlehunt value, scientifically speaking, so don’t panic if at first glance they seem too hard!

> IQ?

•Puzzles can originate from anywhere. My personal favorites come from Pittsburgh puzzlehunts on campus.

> DASH?

•Wondering if $ \sqrt{16} $ should be $ 4 $ or $ -4 $? Take the puzzlehunt and you’ll find the answer!

> Root?

•Puzzlehunt helps you learn how to stay fit and take care of yourself.

> ?

•Puzzles are so important to our lives that even musicians need puzzlehunts to perform properly!

> Practice?

•When forming a team, make sure to have a puzzlehunt, otherwise it’ll be like AD’s team without AD.

> Captain?

•Feeling disgusted and want others to know? Simply shout “Puzzlehunt!” and everyone around you will start feeling the same thing.

> [random curse word]

•Finally, puzzlehunts are great ways to help identify the nuts and bolts in everything, especially when it comes to specific items.

> Instructions?

Comment: That’s a good idea, but it doesn’t really help me finish the script. Again, I think *Brief* Puzzle Hunt is important here

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

Many kinds of puzzles have a high puzzlehunt value, scientifically speaking, so don’t panic if at first glance they seem too hard!

> ph

Puzzles can originate from anywhere. My personal favorites come from Pittsburgh puzzlehunts on campus.

> halls

Wondering if $\sqrt{16}$ should be 4 or −4? Take the puzzlehunt and you’ll find the answer!

> four

Puzzlehunt helps you learn how to stay fit and take care of yourself.

> running

Puzzles are so important to our lives that even musicians need puzzlehunts to perform properly!

> do

When forming a team, make sure to have a puzzlehunt, otherwise it’ll be like AD’s team without AD.

> head

Feeling disgusted and want others to know? Simply shout “Puzzlehunt!” and everyone around you will start feeling the same thing.

> damn

Finally, puzzlehunts are great ways to help identify the nuts and bolts in everything, especially when it comes to specific items.

> marks

All together:

> Falls for running do head damages.

Comment: Heh, that’s definitely an interesting phrase, but I’m not sure it would fit so well in the context of my speech. Sorry! :)